# How to know when last image reached in lightbox2

Tags: javascript, lightbox2

Using jQuery lightbox2, is there a way to know when the last image is reached? In the options, wrapAround is listed, but that only provides a way to loop back to the start.

I'm interested in calling a function when the last image is reached, is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently lightbox v2 doesn't have an API for events. You should do it manually. Either by tracking:

```
$('body').on('click', '.lb-next', function() {
    //Get the current visible image and its position
});
```

Respectively you can track `.lb-prev`.

Or using a [plugin](https://github.com/RickStrahl/jquery-watch) for tracking changing styles and check wether the image that is going to be shown is the last.